# Is there any good way to rewrite the edgetpu old code by using pycoral api?

Tags: edge-detection, tpu, google-coral

I'm a beginner using coral devboard mini.

I want to start a Smart Bird Feeder project.

https://coral.ai/projects/bird-feeder/

I've been trying to execute the code by referring to
I can't run bird_classify.py.

The error is as follows
untimeError: Internal: Unsupported data type in custom op handler: 0Node number 0 (edgetpu-custom-op) failed to prepare.

Originally, the samples in this project seemed to be deprecated, and
The edgetpu requires an old runtimeversion of 13, instead of the current 14.
(tflite is 2.5 ) I have downloaded it directly and re-installed it in

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packagesm

, but I cannot uninstall the new version and cannot match the version.
Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I've decided to give up on running the same environment as the sample, and use the pycoralapi to run the
If there is a good way to rewrite the code to use pycoral, please let me know.

Thanks

#!/usr/bin/python3

```
"""
Coral Smart Bird Feeder

Uses ClassificationEngine from the EdgeTPU API to analyze animals in
camera frames. Sounds a deterrent if a squirrel is detected.

Users define model, labels file, storage path, deterrent sound, and
optionally can set this to training mode for collecting images for a custom
model.

"""

import argparse
import time
import re
import imp
import logging
import gstreamer

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu')

from edgetpu.classification.engine import ClassificationEngine
from PIL import Image
from playsound import playsound

from pycoral.adapters import classify
from pycoral.adapters import common
from pycoral.utils.dataset import read_label_file
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter

def save_data(image,results,path,ext='png'):
    """Saves camera frame and model inference results
    to user-defined storage directory."""
    tag = '%010d' % int(time.monotonic()*1000)
    name = '%s/img-%s.%s' %(path,tag,ext)
    image.save(name)
    print('Frame saved as: %s' %name)
    logging.info('Image: %s Results: %s', tag,results)

def load_labels(path):
    """Parses provided label file for use in model inference."""
    p = re.compile(r'\s*(\d+)(.+)')
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
      lines = (p.match(line).groups() for line in f.readlines())
      return {int(num): text.strip() for num, text in lines}

def print_results(start_time, last_time, end_time, results):
    """Print results to terminal for debugging."""
    inference_rate = ((end_time - start_time) * 1000)
    fps = (1.0/(end_time - last_time))
    print('\nInference: %.2f ms, FPS: %.2f fps' % (inference_rate, fps))
    for label, score in results:
      print(' %s, score=%.2f' %(label, score))

def do_training(results,last_results,top_k):
    """Compares current model results to previous results and returns
    true if at least one label difference is detected. Used to collect
    images for training a custom model."""
    new_labels = [label[0] for label in results]
    old_labels = [label[0] for label in last_results]
    shared_labels  = set(new_labels).intersection(old_labels)
    if len(shared_labels) < top_k:
      print('Difference detected')
      return True

def user_selections():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model', required=True,
                        help='.tflite model path')
    parser.add_argument('--labels', required=True,
                        help='label file path')
    parser.add_argument('--top_k', type=int, default=3,
                        help='number of classes with highest score to display')
    parser.add_argument('--threshold', type=float, default=0.1,
                        help='class score threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--storage', required=True,
                        help='File path to store images and results')
    parser.add_argument('--sound', required=True,
                        help='File path to deterrent sound')
    parser.add_argument('--print', default=False, required=False,
                        help='Print inference results to terminal')
    parser.add_argument('--training', default=False, required=False,
                        help='Training mode for image collection')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    """Creates camera pipeline, and pushes pipeline through ClassificationEngine
    model. Logs results to user-defined storage. Runs either in training mode to
    gather images for custom model creation or in deterrent mode that sounds an
    'alarm' if a defined label is detected."""
    args = user_selections()
    print("Loading %s with %s labels."%(args.model, args.labels))
    engine = ClassificationEngine(args.model)
    labels = load_labels(args.labels)
    storage_dir = args.storage

    #Initialize logging file
    logging.basicConfig(filename='%s/results.log'%storage_dir,
                        format='%(asctime)s-%(message)s',
                        level=logging.DEBUG)

    last_time = time.monotonic()
    last_results = [('label', 0)]
    def user_callback(image,svg_canvas):
        nonlocal last_time
        nonlocal last_results
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        results = engine.classify_with_image(image, threshold=args.threshold, top_k=args.top_k)
        end_time = time.monotonic()
        results = [(labels[i], score) for i, score in results]

        if args.print:
          print_results(start_time,last_time, end_time, results)

        if args.training:
          if do_training(results,last_results,args.top_k):
            save_data(image,results, storage_dir)
        else:
          #Custom model mode:
          #The labels can be modified to detect/deter user-selected items
          if results[0][0] !='background':
            save_data(image, storage_dir,results)
          if 'fox squirrel, eastern fox squirrel, Sciurus niger' in results:
            playsound(args.sound)
            logging.info('Deterrent sounded')

        last_results=results
        last_time = end_time
    result = gstreamer.run_pipeline(user_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you follow one of the examples available from the coral examples.  There is an example named classify_image.py which uses the edgetpu (tflite) that I found works.  After you install the coral examples, you have to drill down through the directory hierarchy.  So, in my case, from root it is:  /home/pi/ml-projects/coral/pycoral/tensorflow/examples/lite/examples.  There are 17 files in that last examples directory.  I'm using: numpy 1.19.3, pycoral 2.0.0, scipy 1.7.1, tensorflow 2.4.0, tflite-runtime 2.5.0.post1.  I've installed the following edgetpu-runtime: edgetpu_runtime_20201105.zip.

Comment: Here's a link to an example code file: https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/blob/master/examples/detect_image.py - this came right out of the examples directory, I've run it and it works.